# Pygame circle and its associated rect for collision detection

Tags: python, pygame

I am having an issue with Pygame drawing a circle and its associated rect.  When I draw a circle such as pygame.draw.circle(surface, color, center, radius) it creates a rect.  I am attempting to do collision detection using pygame.collidepoint(event.pos) where event.pos is the position of a mouse click.  The size of my window is 500x400 and has a black background and the drawn circle is blue.  When I click outside of the circle (in the black background), the circle should increase in size by multiplying the radius by an int.  Conversely, when a click is registered inside of the circle, the circle shrinks by dividing the radius by an int.

The problem I am having is that the rect is not actually the same size as the circle such that when you click on the background when the circle is large but not completely filling the window, it shrinks instead of getting bigger (i.e. it registers a click inside the circle).  At a certain point, the rect associated with the circle becomes the same size as the window even if the circle is not completely filling it which results in registering a click inside.

My question is how can I use hit detection for the circle only and not the rect which is larger than the actual circle?

Here is the relevant code:

```
def handleMouseDown(self, position):
    if self.circle.collidepoint(position):
        self.radius = self.radius // 2
    else:
        self.radius = self.radius * 2
    self.draw()

def draw(self):
    self.surface.fill(self.black)
    self.circle = pygame.draw.circle(self.surface, self.color, self.center, self.radius)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just calculate the distance between the center of the circle and the position of the mouse click:

```
x1, y1 = position
x2, y2 = self.circle.center
distance = math.hypot(x1 - x2, y1 - y2)
```

Then check if this distance is smaller or equal the radius of the circle:

```
if distance <= self.radius:
    self.radius = self.radius // 2
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much sloth!  I implemented this into the code and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

When a click is detected, have the handler determine if it is actually inside the circle.  Otherwise ignore it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I believe I am doing a check to determine if the click was inside the circle with collidepoint.  Unfortunately, this only checks whether the click was inside of the (invisible) rect created by the pygame.draw.circle and not actually the visible, drawn circle.